# Are Vim's regex magics compatible with well-known regex classes?

Tags: regular-expression

Many Unix tools' regular expression syntaxes are often the POSIX-codified Basic and Extended Regular Expressions (BRE and ERE, respectively), and, in some modern implementations, Perl-style (PCRE being an implementation of this).

Is there a one-to-one correspondence between Vim's levels of magic and such externally defined, but well-known, classes? It looks like `\m` is BRE and `\v` is ERE, except POSIX doesn't include lookarounds.

If such a correspondence exists, is it defined somewhere? [`pattern.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html) has only one mention of `POSIX`.

Or do we have to stick with "magic" to describe Vim regular expressions?

Comment: Pretty sure `\v` includes `<>` word boundaries, which AFAIK is unique to Vim. So no, just describe them as "Vim regex." (Not posting as an answer because I'm not positive)

Comment: @Doorknob, I think you might find find [this discussion of answers-as-comments](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3927/135943) interesting.  Since your comment has three upvotes and no comments responding to tell you it's incorrect, it's *probably* correct (I'm not sure), but suggested edits et. al. are impossible to improve its accuracy.  As a posted answer, it could be edited for improved accuracy, upvoted, downvoted, responded to, etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In summary, no. Vim's regex is a unique flavour, and there are no options to make it behave more like another flavour.

I think this is a good thing.

## Magic

The `'magic'` option doesn't change the flavour of regex that Vim uses. It simply inverts the behaviour of many `\`-escaped atoms.

For example, by default, `+` is a literal `+` character, where `\+` means "one or more of the preceding atom". In contrast, `*` means "zero or more of the preceding atom", while `\*` is a literal `*`. Many people find this quite confusing. Using `\v` in your pattern makes it a bit more consistent. `:help 'magic'` gives a good summary:

> ```
> after:    \v       \m       \M       \V         matches ~
>                 'magic' 'nomagic'
>           $        $        $        \$         matches end-of-line
>           .        .        \.       \.         matches any character
>           *        *        \*       \*         any number of the previous atom
>           ()       \(\)     \(\)     \(\)       grouping into an atom
>           |        \|       \|       \|         separating alternatives
>           \a       \a       \a       \a         alphabetic character
>           \\       \\       \\       \\         literal backslash
>           \.       \.       .        .          literal dot
>           \{       {        {        {          literal '{'
>           a        a        a        a          literal 'a'
> ```

Personally, I think the default behaviour is nice for code files, where it's not uncommon to search for things like `foo(`, using the literal `(`.

## Vim's own regex flavour

I've witnessed many people wishing Vim supported PCRE. Personally, I wish other tools supported Vim's flavour of regex. It has some capabilities that are either impossible or too cumbersome to achieve in PCRE.

### Impossible in PCRE

[Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is a common feature where you can assert that a pattern either does or does not match before or after the pattern you're trying to match. For example, the PCRE pattern `q(?!u)` (or Vim regex pattern `qu\@!`) matches a `q` that's not followed by a `u`. (This is more correct than `q[^u]`, which requires that there is *some* character after the `q`.)

#### Variable-length negative lookbehind

PCRE, and many other flavours, have a restriction that a negative lookbehind pattern must be of a fixed length. That means that a pattern like `(?<![a-z]{3})foo`, meaning "the string `foo` *not preceded by* exactly 3 lowercase letters") is fine, but `(?<![a-z]+)foo` (meaning "the string `foo` not preceded by *any number* of lowercase letters") is not.

This restriction doesn't exist in Vim. In Vim, a pattern like `\([a-z]\+\)\@<!foo`, while maybe a bit ugly to look at, is perfectly valid.

### Easier in Vim regex

Some things are a lot nicer in Vim's flavour of regex.

#### Start and end of match anchors

The most notable, in my opinion, are the `\zs` and `\ze` anchors. These allow you to specify the start and end of the match. For example, `foo(\zs.*\ze)` matches only what's between the `(` and `)` in a function call like `foo(...)`. This can be done in PCRE, but it requires the use of lookaround, which is slightly tedious: `(?<=foo\().*(?=\))`

#### Prefix matching

Another cool thing that Vim can do is match any prefix (including the empty prefix) of a particular sequence of characters. For example, to match on `f`, `fo`, `foo`, or `food`, the pattern `f\%[ood]` can be used. In PCRE, such a pattern would look like `f(o(od?)?)?`. (Imagine that for a longer string!)

#### Matching cursor, line, and column positions

Vim's regex has some anchors for matching positions in the buffer.

- `\%23c` matches column 23
- `\%<23c` matches *before* column 23
- `\%>23c` matches *after* column 23
- `\%16l` matches line 16

  - Similar to column, there are anchors for *before* or *after* a line number
- `\%#` matches the cursor position

  - This is useful for things like [highlighting trailing whitespace except when you're typing at the end of the line](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces)

---

I think it's worth-while to embrace Vim's flavour of regex. It's well-suited for use in a text editor used primarily for programming, and it's quite powerful.