# Find and replace using regular expressions

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I have a file with a bunch of user defaults in. I want to change some of the text, but I'm struggling coming up with a matcher and replacer. Using the following example:

```
###############################################################################
# Trackpad, mouse, keyboard, Bluetooth accessories, and input                 #
###############################################################################

# Trackpad: enable tap to click for this user and for the login screen
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool true
```

I'd like to replace `# Trackpad: ...` with `running "Trackpad: ..."`

Breaking the problem down, I came up with something using a regex tester:

```
/\n\n#\s(.*)/g
```

If I try and use this in Vim it doesn't work for me:

```
:/\n\n#\s(.*)/running "\1"/g
```

I guess my problem boils down to two specific questions:

1. How can I avoid searching for `\n` characters, and instead make sure `#` doesn't appear at the end of the search group?
2. How can I effectively use capture groups?

---

There are some great answers below. Hard to choose between all three, however I feel the chosen answer is the most accurate for my original spec. I recommend you try all three answers with the [actual file](https://github.com/squarefrog/dotfiles/blob/f4c5607f1826e85b55fb58e9c81b474a3f67ce91/osx/setup_defaults.sh) to see how you feel about them.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just to be clear… I believe you asked for this to be the result of the substitution?

```
###############################################################################
# Trackpad, mouse, keyboard, Bluetooth accessories, and input                 #
###############################################################################

running "Trackpad: enable tap to click for this user and for the login screen"
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool true
```

In that case, I recommend the following command:

`:%s/\n\n#\s\+\(.*\)/^M^Mrunning "\1"/`

#### Explanation of the pattern

`:s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` is the [substitute](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute) command.  The percent sign in `:%s` makes it work on the whole file, rather than just the current line.

The `\n\n` says that the line of interest must occur after a blank line.  If you didn't care about the preceding blank line, then `^` would suffice.

`#\s\+` matches a hash character followed by one or more whitespace characters.  `\(.*\)` captures all subsequent text on the line.

#### Explanation of the replacement text

`^M^M` inserts two ends of lines to replace the `\n\n` that were present in the pattern.  Otherwise, the text would get moved to the end of the line preceding the blank line.  To type each `^M`, press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd>.

Then, insert the string `running`, followed by whatever was captured in the parentheses within double-quotes.

Comment: I am unable to edit your answer but I believe you meant `:%s/\v\n\n#\s+(.*)/^M^Mrunning "\1"/` (added the "magic" flag). It is really hard to pick a correct answer for my original question, but I feel this answer is the closest to my original expected answer. It is also the only one that works throughout the whole file without any need for selecting a range.

Comment: IIRC you can use `\r` instead of `^M` to get new lines?

Answer (score 19):

I would use something like:

```
:s/^#\s\+\(.\{-}\):/running "\1":/
```

- `^#` to match the `#` character anchored at the start of the line (this answers question 1)
- `\s\+` to match any whitespace one or more times
- `\(` to start a group (this answers question 2)
- `.\{-}\` to match any character 0 or more times *in a non-greedy way*; this is diffferent from `.*` in that it tries to match as little as possible, and not as much as possible. Try adding a `:` character in the comment to see why this matters
- `\)` to end the subgroup.
- `:` matches a literal `:`

We then replace this with the text you want, and use `\1` to refer to the group we captured.

> I came up with something using a regex tester

Regular expression syntax is a bit like wiki syntax: there are a bunch of them, they all look alike at a glance, none of them is obviously better than any other, but there are many differences.

Today, the so called "Perl compatible" regular expressions are the de-facto default in most languages, but Vim regular expressions are *not* compatible with Perl-compatible expressions! Vim regexp syntax goes back to at least the '70's, when Perl wasn't even around.

You can see this with the subgroups, where you have to use `\(` and not `(` (this is compatible with POSIX 'basic' syntax, but not with the more common POSIX 'extended' syntax or Perl syntax). You can control this by adding the `\v` flag in a pattern (See [`:help /\v`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/%5CV) for details), this will make it "more compatible", but not completely (You still have to use `.{-}` for non-greedy matches for example)

So this might explain why using "a regex tester" almost, but not quite,  works.

http://www.vimregex.com/ as a good overview/cheatsheet of Vim regexps.

Comment: Great answer, especially with why regex != regex. As for your search and replace, it's a bit tricky as the comment may or may not have a `:`. See the full file for details https://github.com/squarefrog/dotfiles/blob/master/osx/setup_defaults.sh

Comment: this does not find & replace in the whole file

Answer (score 9):

You can:

- search for lines that don't end in `#`: `:/[^#]$/`
- replace `#\s(.*)` at the start of the line: `s/\v^#\s(.*)/running "\1"/`

To use groups, you need to either:

- escape the brackets so that they become part of the regex syntax: `\(.*\)`, or
- use ["magic"](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2279/205) by beginning the expression with `\v`: `s/\v...`

Combining it:

```
:/[^#]$/s/\v^#\s(.*)/running "\1"/
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, thanks for including an explanation of what the tags mean rather than just the text I needed to write.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear that the brackets have to be escaped in order to become part of the regex syntax. I always had an issue with regex groups in getting them to work.