# How to use the JS regex engine instead of the built in engine?

Tags: search, regular-expression, substitute

Is it possible to use the javascript regex engine instead of built-in one for search and substitute?

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: @herbwolfe because i'm js developer and want use `()` capture group without escaping `\(\)`. I used to use js regexp, because i use it every day. It seems to me that js regexpes more human-readable than vim's

Comment: Have you tried prepending search pattern with `\v` - which is `very magic`? This makes Vim treat `()` special without escaping. Read more here`:h \v`

Comment: @grodzik not only because of escaping i want to use another engine. It concerns a lot of aspects, like `?` instead of `\=`, so i didn't found `\d` working in vim engine

Comment: so vim's `[ ]` doesn't require escaping `\` and it makes its syntax more complex and unintuitive

Comment: not possible. Because Vim regexp likely allows regex atoms that cannot be expressed by the JS regex enging (e.g. cursor position, regexp engine, etc)

Comment: @christian what is 'regex atoms'?

Comment: Have you tried `:help atoms`?

Answer (score 5):

I can understand the frustration in having to learn a new<sup>1</sup> regular expression dialect when you already know one well, but it's not possible to change which dialect Vim uses.

Vim's default regular expressions make it quicker to search for the textual elements frequently found in code. Thus you can search for for e.g. `foo()` simply with the expression `foo()`. Personally, this isn't to my taste, so I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap / /\v
nnoremap ? ?\v
```

This means my searches begin in "very magic" mode, so much less escaping is required to get to regular expression features such as grouping. If I need a normal "magic" expression I can simply delete the `\v` by pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

However, some of the other differences (e.g. the syntax for lookaround) you're just going to have to learn afresh, I'm afraid. The best place if you're already well versed in regular expressions is probably the reference documentation (`:help regexp`), but there's also info in the user guide (`:help usr_27.txt`).

[This previous answer by tommcdo](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2279/343) explains some of the benefits you will get from doing so.

<sub>1: New to you, that is. Vim's regular expressions pre-date most other current dialects.</sub>

Comment: This is unfulfilling. I need to test a regex that will be used by V8 and I can't use Vim for that, because it involves look-around syntax.